# Vakil 6.4.G: Regrading a ring generated in arbitrary degrees

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

I'm working through Vakil's FOAG currently and am stuck with how to apply the hint in problem 6.4.G; the problem states

> Suppose $S_\bullet$ is generated over $S_0$ by $f_1, \dots, f_n$. Find $d$ such that $S_{d\bullet}$ is finitely generated in "new" degree 1 (= "old" degree $d$). (This is surprisingly tricky, so here is a hint. Suppose there generators $x_1, \dots, x_n$ of degrees $d_1, \dots, d_n$ respectively. Show that any monomial $x_1^{a_1}\dots x_n^{a_n}$ of degree at least $nd_1\dots d_n$ has $a_i \geq (\prod_j d_j)\ /\, d_i$ for some $i$. Show that the $(nd_1\dots d_n)$th Veronese subring is generated by elements in “new” degree 1.)

The first part of the hint is easy to show by picking $i$ such that $a_id_i = \max_{1\leq j \leq n} a_i d_i$. Then for the monomial $x_1^{a_1}\dots x_n^{a_n}$ of degree $a_1d_1 + \dots + a_nd_n \geq nd_1 \dots d_n$, we have
$$
na_id_i \geq a_1d_1 + \dots + a_nd_n \geq nd_1 \dots d_n
$$
giving us the relation we need.

However I get a bit stuck trying to apply this to the last sentence — how does this tell us that the $(nd_1\dots d_n)$th Veronese subring $S_{nd_1\dots d_n \bullet}$ is generated in degree 1 using the fact that $S_\bullet$ is generated by $x_1, \dots, x_n$ (I'm not entirely sure why both $f_1, \dots, f_n$ and $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are used here).